# How do I change the center of an object for correct rotation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, blender

I have a 3D object that I exported from blender:
[image]

Then I load it into a unity and get a center like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the top of Unity there are two pivot modes

- `Center` automatically uses the "Center of geometry"
- `Pivot` is the actual pivot point of the 3D model

Make sure it says `Pivot`.

[image]

See also [Unity Manual - Positioning GameObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html)